# Python pandas - dataframe pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Hour  DayOfWeek
00    Friday         4
      Wednesday     19
01    Friday         7
07    Saturday       1
      Thursday       3
      Tuesday        3
      Wednesday      5
08    Friday         1
      Monday        17
      Thursday      10
      Tuesday       16
      Wednesday      8
```

and I want to make it into a dataframe like so:

```
Hour   Sunday   Monday   Tuesday   Wednesday   Thursday
01       4        5        6          0           7
03       3        5        6          6           0
05       2        1        8          6           9
11       0        1        8          0           0
12       1        5        7          6           7
15       1        5        6          0           2
```

plus I want to fill the zeros in the hours of the day to be in range 0 untill 23.

it looks like some kind of an advanced indexing in dataframe and I don't know how to do it, any help will be thanksfull!

thank you

Comment: How do you create your second dataframe from your first one ? For exemple tehre is no `Wednsday 19` in your second one ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
print (df.index)
MultiIndex(levels=[[0, 1, 7, 8],
                   ['Friday', 'Monday', 'Saturday', 'Thursday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3], 
                   [0, 5, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1, 3, 4, 5]],
           names=['Hour', 'DayOfWeek'])

print (df.unstack(fill_value=0))
DayOfWeek  Friday  Monday  Saturday  Thursday  Tuesday  Wednesday
Hour                                                             
0               4       0         0         0        0         19
1               7       0         0         0        0          0
7               0       0         1         3        3          5
8               1      17         0        10       16          8
```

and last add [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
print (df.unstack(fill_value=0).reindex(np.arange(24), fill_value=0))

Hour                                                             
0               4       0         0         0        0         19
1               7       0         0         0        0          0
2               0       0         0         0        0          0
3               0       0         0         0        0          0
4               0       0         0         0        0          0
5               0       0         0         0        0          0
6               0       0         0         0        0          0
7               0       0         1         3        3          5
8               1      17         0        10       16          8
9               0       0         0         0        0          0
10              0       0         0         0        0          0
11              0       0         0         0        0          0
12              0       0         0         0        0          0
13              0       0         0         0        0          0
14              0       0         0         0        0          0
15              0       0         0         0        0          0
16              0       0         0         0        0          0
17              0       0         0         0        0          0
18              0       0         0         0        0          0
19              0       0         0         0        0          0
20              0       0         0         0        0          0
21              0       0         0         0        0          0
22              0       0         0         0        0          0
23              0       0         0         0        0          0
```